# Compressed single-sideband modulation?

Tags: rf, communication, modulation, amplitude-modulation, digital-modulation

I've had an idea for a new form of SSB modulation, using half-angle formulas as a basis for compressing the sideband of a SSB voice transmission. However, this idea seems so simple that I feel it must have been proposed previously, even though I can't imagine a practical application except for possibly in the amateur bands.

Can anyone verify having heard of it and what is it called? My searches online and through IEEE Xplore don't reveal anything.

Comment: There's probably no practical need for it, nor research in the field is being performed right now...

Comment: I agree; it isn't really practical. It would likely only ever have very limited uses. I'm an MSEE student attempting to design a software-defined HF radio, and my adviser/mentor has tasked me to create a "more original" form of modulation in addition to building the radio. He's not so concerned with practicality as he is with having a "new" idea proposed.

Comment: well if you searched on IEEEXplore and did not find it that should be original enough. if you want to explain your idea just lay it out, it's not likely that somebody will steal it. ask something like 'I think that you could modulate so and so, are there any disadvantages/why doesn't anybody do that?"

Comment: Thanks, Vladimir! I think I'll do that as soon as I have a more detailed description of the theory.

Comment: It has been stated that it is theoreticly possible to simultaneously angle and amplitude modulate a carrier to make SSB.I am unsure that the guy that said this in the 1970s is still alive .This would be novel to keep the prof happy .Also you could then use a much more efficient final amplifier that would give a genuine size reduction.I started researching this trying to propose a 4th method of SSB generation .I got busy so havenot done anything more .SSB is alive and well .